# Does a white noise process have constant variance by definition?

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition, stationary-processes, noise

If you'll look up for the definition of a (discrete) *white noise* process on the web, you'll find some sources that say:

*"white noise is defined by zero mean, finite **and constant** variance, zero autocorrelation"*

and roughly the same amount of them that say:

*"white noise is defined by zero mean, finite variance, zero autocorrelation"*.

In the latter (e.g. [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise)), "white noise" encompasses also the case of *heteroskedastic white noise* - where the variance isn't constant. Obviously, stationarity is dropped.

Which of these two is "the" standard definition? Am I missing something?

Comment: I was under the impression that the key feature of white noise was the constant power spectral density.

Comment: I think this is the case where it depends on what you're studying. Terms are usually thrown around...but as you said, if it's stationary then it's constant. But if the thing you want to model has heteroschedastic errors then the white noise is non-constant.